# Activate function once 12 characters are entered into text box

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am new to MVC 4 and making an internet application that uses a hand scanner to fill a text box. I was hoping to have it automatically activate a JavaScript function once the barcode has been scanned.

Scanning the barcode fills the active textbox with 12 characters,  and I currently have to click a button after each scan. Is there a way to automatically activate the button or JavaScript function after the barcode is scanned, or after the 12th character is entered?

Comment: The text box is getting dynamically filled or is someone typing?

Comment: @DevlshOne According to OP it is filled by barcode scanner

Comment: We'll just have to see if his scanner routine supports keyboard events. In my experience, they typically do.

Comment: I've only worked with a few scanners, but all of them were able to send a keypress to the computer after a scan. So we would program them to add a return or tab after the scan. That might be easiest for you.

Comment: A `tab` or `enter` press would be great - then `change` would work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#myTextBox').attr('maxlength','12');
$(document).on('change','#myTextbox',function(e) {
    if ($(this).val().length >= 12) {
        $('#myButton').click();
    }
});
```

**OR**, if the scanner routine supports keyboard events:

```
$('#myTextBox').attr('maxlength','12');
$(document).on('keyup','#myTextbox',function(e) {
    if ($(this).val().length >= 12) {
        $('#myButton').click();
    }
});
```

Either way, this solution requires [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/), a Javascript library.

Comment: Scanner is filling the texbox, not keyboard

Comment: @YuriyGalanter, I asked - the OP did not answer.

Comment: I would use `>= 12` rather an `== 12`, just in case someone pastes a block of text into it. If it is expected to only ever be 12 characters, it might also be prudent to put a `maxlength` attribute on it.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter, most barcode scanners work just like a USB keyboard as far as the computer is concerned.

Comment: @jmoerdyk really? Sorry didn't know that. And do they provide events like 'keyup'?

Comment: @user1990577 Are you inferring that 4Kb of additional code is going to destroy performance?

Comment: $("#myTextbox").change(function(){}});

Comment: @DevlshOne jquery is not needed. At least here.

Comment: @EricFrick I'm not sure about using `change` here. That would require gaining and losing focus, which may never be the case. I like my `keyup` solution better - IF the scanner routine supports it.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work in Internet Explorer. IE requires the input to lose focus before an onchange event is generated.

Comment: @user1990577 Great, would you please provide a pure JS solution to prove your point?

Comment: tried the first suggestion and got this:

JavaScript runtime error: '$this' is undefined

Comment: Apologies... I had a typo and have made some edits. Try it now.

Comment: That got rid of the error and it works other than that i have to click the page in order for it to activate. As soon as I click anywhere on the page, then it activates the function.

Comment: That's the situation I was concerned about using `change`. Try the 2nd version with the `keyup` and see what happens.

Comment: Same issue, have to click to activate.

Comment: the barcode scanner I'm using is a MS210-1bg if that helps at all [link](http://www.barcodesinc.com/pdf/Unitech/ms210.pdf)

Comment: Do you have the user manual? Are you running it in USB mode or Keyboard mode? Did you install the RS232-Keyboard utility? You're going to have to somehow make the scanner emulate the keyboard or look for a USB interface listener.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval to check length periodicaly. Something like

```
var i=setInterval(function() {
   if (document.getElementById('myTextBox').value.length >=12) {
      clearInterval(i);

      // Execute your code here

   }
}, 100)
```

This code check length of the Textbox every 100 milliseconds, and when desired length is reached - you can execute your code

Comment: This is a waste of electricity. Listening to an event triggered by the text box is the sane way to do it.

Comment: @Renan yes IF barcode scanner support those events. The method above assumes it doesnt

Answer (score 1):

Well, this would be enough in most cases.

```
function functionThatActivatesWhenTwelveCharactersInForm(){

}
```

JS:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="if(this.value.length>=12){functionThatActivatesWhenTwelveCharactersInForm()}; return true;">
```